# Setup Xcode 7 to call MATLAB 2013b

Tags: matlab, xcode7

I have been trying to setup MATLAB on Xcode 7 however I have found it very confusing and most of my online research about the topic resulted in out dated answers that does not match the version of MATLAB or Xcode that I have.

is there any Vid or a helpful link like this one available? http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91611-how-can-i-build-an-engine-application-using-the-xcode-ide-on-mac

I am looking for more up to date more related to MATLAB2013 and Xcode 7 answers because a lot of the stuff in the link above do not exist anymore.

Please help I have been trying for a week before I write here.

Comment: I have posted my own way to solve it >>> I've posted a link to a 20min long video as a solution but it has been deleted >>.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVX3Yq7s88g